# How to seed Rails db with images from the asset pipeline (paperclip)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to refactor my Rails application for a client.

I've created a new model with the relevant columns (`title`, `description`, `body`).

I need to add `image` to this model, but I don't know what data type to use and I read that it's a bad idea to put images into the database.

At the moment I'm trying to seed the db with all the data from the client and struggling to find a way to seed in the images. So far I have the following:

```
Model.create!([
  {
    title: "Title",
    description: "Some decription",
    body: "Here is the body",
    sort_order: 1 
  },
  { 
    title: "Title",
    description: "Some description",
    body: "Here is the body",
    sort_order: 2
  }
])
```

Should I add `image` to the model so I can populate it using the seed file? If so, what's the data type - perhaps `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Public Images

If you are referencing an image in the public folder, store the root-relative path to the image as a `string` in the database. (E.g., if your image file is `project/public/images/pic.jpg`, then you would have `image: '/images/pic.jpg'` in the seeds.

### Asset Managed Images

If you are referencing an image in your assets, things can get a touch more complicated (unless you’ve ill-advisedly turned off the `config.assets.digest` config). You’ll want to use the path to the asset in the seeds file (like with the first part of this answer referencing files in the public folder), but then when you want to link to the image in your views you’ll have to use Rails’ `image_tag` to get the asset-managed url for the image.

If for some reason you want to be able to get the asset-managed path to the image in any way other than `image_tag` in views, it gets a bit complicated. You can find some more details on working with the asset pipeline in the official [Rails guide to The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

### Images stored in Database

If you are storing the image file data in the database, you would use a `binary` field (not `string`). You could load the image data with a call to `File.read`. E.g.:

```ruby
image_data = File.read('path/to/image.jpg')
Model.create!([
  {
    ...
    image: image_data
  },
  ...
])
```

You’ll need to add a custom controller method & route to deliver the image data as a file to the client (be sure to handle the mime type correctly for that).

Personally, in those cases where I’ve chosen to store raw file data in the database, I prefer to have a separate table just for the data and then join it to the main model as needed. (In this case, there would be your existing `images` table, and it would be joined to a table named something like `image_files` with just one field, aside from `id`):

```ruby
create_table :image_files do |t|
  t.binary :data
end
```

And then you could reference that from your `images` table:

```ruby
t.belongs_to :image_file
```

(or put the reference to the `images` table in the `image_files` table.)

As to the arguments for/against storing raw file data in a database, in general it’s sub-optimal (you lose the benefits of having the web-server directly sending the files from the filesystem and have to have Rails intervene). But it can make sense in some cases (such as when you want to restrict access — e.g., to specific users).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I was going back and forth between adding in image to the model. I'm working with asset managed images so this was really helpful.