# how to reference to an image in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Carrierwave to upload images associated to my User model, which has a corresponding `picture` attribute that contains the name of the image file in a string field. Usually the name of the uploaded picture is stored in `public/uploads`. 
Now I would like to seed my development database with sample users including the associated path to the profile picture. I tried to store my `pic1.jpg`, `pic2.jpg`, `pic3.jpg` pictures in `public/images` and reference to these pictures in `db/seeds.rb` as `picture: '/images/pic1.jpg'` etc, like Grant Neufeld suggested in an [old stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48064693/5078888). In view the picture is included using the following code:

```
<%= image_tag @user.picture.url if @user.picture? %>
```

However this does not work, the image is not loaded into view, because the picture attribute is nil. I also tried to store my pictures in `app/assets/images` and reference them as `picture: 'pic1.jpg'`, `picture: 'pic2.jpg'`, `picture: 'pic3.jpg'` in `db/seeds.rb` without result.

Below is my `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
User.create!(name:  "Example User",
         email: "example@railstutorial.org",
         password:              "foobar",
         password_confirmation: "foobar",
         admin: true,
         politics: 'left',
         car: true,
         pets: 'I like horses and bears',
         music: 'American country and folk',
         picture: 'pic1.jpg',
         profile: 'I like music and the Ruby and Python programming languages',
         activated: true,
         activated_at: Time.zone.now)

User.create!(name:  "Super-friendly User",
        email: "example-101@railstutorial.org",
        password:              "PassWord-0",
        password_confirmation: "PassWord-0",
        admin: true,
        smoker: true,
        politics: 'left',
        car: true,
        pets: 'I like turtles and whales',
        car_pets: true,
        music: 'Jazz and blues',
        picture: 'pic2.jpg',
        profile: 'I like music and drinking',
        activated: true,
        activated_at: Time.zone.now)

User.create!(name:  "Friendly User",
        email: "example-102@railstutorial.org",
        password:              "PassWord-0",
        password_confirmation: "PassWord-0",
        politics: 'right',
        car: true,
        pets: 'I like snakes and gorillas',
        music: 'pop and classics',
        picture: 'pic3.jpg',
        profile: 'I like music and hiking',
        activated: true,
        activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name:  name,
           email: email,
           password:              password,
           password_confirmation: password,
           activated: true,
           activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

Comment: Can you please include your `seeds.rb` file?

Comment: @gmaliar I included my `seeds.rb` file in the original message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are saving your images under `public/images`, Carrierwave requires that you pass an IO object to the Rails model, so to set it up correctly in the `seeds.rb` file you instead need to do:

```rb
User.create!(
  name:  "Example User",
  email: "example@railstutorial.org",
  password:              "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar",
  admin: true,
  politics: 'left',
  car: true,
  pets: 'I like horses and bears',
  music: 'American country and folk',
  picture: File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'images', 'pic1.jpg')),
  profile: 'I like music and the Ruby and Python programming languages',
  activated: true,
  activated_at: Time.zone.now
)
```

See that I've changed `picture` to `File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'images', 'pic1.jpg'))`